# Can abstraction be achieved using concrete classes?

Tags: java, oop, interface, abstract-class, abstraction

I have tried my best finding answer to this question but in vain.
So, I was asked this question in an interview and I answered YES. Since abstraction is nothing but simply hiding the implementation details from user, such that the user need not worry about the implementation and only knows about the method signature(Type of object that need to be passed and the return type). Based on the type of object passed the developer can decide the implementation and return the corresponding result.
So, according to me this can also be done using concrete normal classes as below.

```
public class LearnAbstraction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Tiger();
        SpeakingAnimal sa = new SpeakingAnimal();
        sa.getAnimalToSpeak(animal);
    }
}

class SpeakingAnimal {
    public void getAnimalToSpeak(Animal animal){
        animal.speak();
    }
}

class Animal{
    public void speak(){
        System.out.println("I am an Animal");
    }
}

class Tiger extends Animal {
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("I am an Animal and Tiger");
    }
}

class Horse extends Animal {
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("I am an Animal and Horse");
    }
}
```

I know it is not a correct way to achieve abstraction and it must be done using Interfaces or abstract classes. But, the question is whether abstraction can be achieved using concrete classes or not(Let's leave the appropriate way aside). So, is it correct to say YES as the answer to this question?

Comment: Interview questions are seldom yes/no affairs.  The interviewer would have  been after some kind of explanation of why you can or can't implement abstraction using concrete classes.  So to simply say "YES", is the wrong answer, although technically correct, as you've demonstrated.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem So that means a YES along with the explanation and an example?

Comment: I would argue that `SpeakingAnimal::getAnimalToSpeak()` is not performing an abstract action. It is very clear that its job is to force an animal to speak. Therefore, the abstract part is `Animal::speak()`. I agree with Dawood that an interview is a time you argue your point to convince your interviewer. There is no right/wrong most of the time. Umm edit: You need to debate, not argue. DON'T argue with the interviewers.

Comment: Ummmmmmmm, YES.

Comment: I c/wouldn't answer it straight away without getting a little clarification on what they mean by abstraction. Certainly, you show an example of achieving a *layer of abstraction* but if you take it more literal, particularly if it's more of a language question, maybe not so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An abstract class cannot produce instances; you can ensure it doesn't by declaring a private constructor.

Here is an example:

```
class Animal{
    private Animal() {
    }

    public void speak(){
        System.out.println("I am an Animal");
    }

    static class Tiger extends Animal {
        public void speak() {
            System.out.println("I am an Animal and Tiger");
        }
    }

    static class Horse extends Animal {
        public void speak() {
            System.out.println("I am an Animal and Horse");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While some of what you say is technically correct, it seems largely misunderstood to me. An abstract class is one that is declared `abstract`, and then you need no constructor trick to prevent instantiation. The private constructor makes sure that instances of the class *and of concrete subclasses* can only be instantiated inside the class, that’s something completely different. So with your example class no tigers or horses can ever be created. Also you don’t seem to answer the question?